# Zeppelin can't execute Hive use shell

Tags: hadoop, apache-zeppelin

I am using Zeppelin-0.5.6.

[image]

I check the log and find something below:

[image]

However, it works well when I use terminal.

I also tried some other hive commands. When I used commands below in Zeppelin I got the same error while it worked well in terminal.

> %sh
>
> hive -e "show databases"

Can anybody help?

Thanks.